# Shells Question: $y =9 - x^2, y =9, x =3$; revolve about the line $y =9$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to use shells to answer this question, and I am a bit stumped I graphed it and I can't seem to get the answer.

$y=9-x^2$, $y = 9 \ , \ x = 3$

I got this as my template but the answer is supposed to be:

$\frac{243}{5}\pi$

This is dummy, attempt model I have for the solution:

$$V\ =\ 2\pi \int_{0}^{9}(y\ \cdot \ \sqrt{9-y} \ )dy$$

Is this the answer for the question?

$$2\pi \int_{0}^{9}(9-y)(3-\sqrt{9-y})dy$$

Because it yields the same result on the desmos calculator. I still don't know how I got it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of shell is $$(9-y)$$ and the height of shell is $$3-x=3-\sqrt {9-y}$$ 
Thus the second integral is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The correct shell integral expression is

$$2\pi \int_{0}^{9}(9-y)(3-\sqrt{9-y})dy=\frac{343}{5}\pi$$

where $9-y$ is the radius of the shell and $3-\sqrt{9-y}$ is the height of the shell.